# How to update the context of a workflow using a secret that is updated by another workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow `CI` that underneath uses two reusable workflows, `get-secret` and `run-tests`. The `run-tests` workflow needs a secret and for this reason it `needs` the completion of the `get-secret` workflow.

Unfortunately `output` doesn't provide the flexibility that we need due to the fact we cannot output secrets from the `get-secret` workflow.

The solution I thought of involves using `gh` CLI, meaning that my `get-secret` workflow uses `gh secret set` to set the secret at repo level instead of trying to output it.

The problem is now that the `CI` workflow doesn't seem to have the updated value of the secret set by `get-secret`. The first time I run `CI` it runs `get-secret` which completes and then it runs `run-tests` which fails, for example, because the secret it needs it outdated. By rerunning exclusively `run-tests` it will succeed because it will now use the updated value of the secret.

Is there a way to force the update of the context of the running job to grab the latest value of the repo secret? It feels to me that when the GitHub Actions runs by using a snapshot of the secrets and if these are updated the job has no visibility over it. This is just an assumption.

Comment: You may resolve this by not using a reusable workflow for the `run-tests` workflow, but a `workflow_dispatch` or `repository_dispatch` workflow trigger instead, that would be called by the `get-secret` workflow before it ends. That way, you'll avoid the outdated secret.

Comment: @GuiFalourd thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I do need the `get-secret` and `run-tests` to be separate. `get-secret`  is a workflow that is used for different cases and that's why it's an isolated and independent piece of logic that sometimes is used as dependency before `run-tests`  but some other times it has nothing to do with `run-tests` at all and used for other cases, so it cannot trigger the `run-tests` itself and needs an orchestrator on top

Comment: Your orchestrator could call the `run-tests` workflow afterwards by using a dispatch event instead of calling the reusable-workflow. To give more context about what I understand here: all reusable-workflows are pre-configured when initiating the main workflow calling them, that's why the error occur the first time you run the workflow and not the second time. To avoid this to happen, you have to call the `run-tests` workflow later, without having it pre-configured. That's the reason why I suggest calling it another way through a dispatch_event.

Comment: @GuiFalourd haven't answered in a few days, sorry, but just had the time again to try your solution. The problem with the workflow_dispatch event, unless I am mistaken, is that it's a fire and forget event. My `CI` workflow needs to see the status of the `run-tests` workflow and not just trigger and forget about it.

Comment: In that case, you probably need more configurations. You would probably also need a callback (dispatch event as well) from the workflow dispatched, and have this workflow validated by your CI. It may be harder to maintain (as it would be 3 workflows chained that way) and not worth the effort.